# Why the Children of Avraham and not Yitzchok and Yacckov?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, shabbat-songs, kol-mikadesh

In the song [Kol Mikadesh](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=83) it says:

> זרע אברהם אוהבו

Translated as: Children of Avraham his Beloved

Why does the song mention only Avraham and not any of the other forefathers in this stament what is special about avraham that he is the only one mentioned in the song?

Answer (score 1):

The Tiferet Hashabat deals with the question why the Paytan (poet?) changed the order of being late leaving the Shabat and being early in getting into it. He explains that it was done for the rhyme: Ohavo, Eruvo, Bo. Maybe we can use this explanation that Zea Avraham Ohavo was used for that reason (the rhyme) , keeping in mind that Bnei Yisrael answer to that definition.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I mean, it could as well have said _zera Yisrael ohavo_ as _zera Avraham ohavo_.

Comment: The phrase zera ... ohavo appears in Chazal only as zera Avraham ohavo. But you are right that the paytan could have said zera Ya'akov bechiro too. But that wouldn't include the Geirim which we see as Bnei Abraham